# Weird positioning problem with only one set of div's

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css-position

On this page -> http://students.cmps.subr.edu/aaron.chauvin/misc/test2.html at the bottom I have some text in two divs that are positioned incorrectly only in IE9... what's wierd is that these are the ONLY divs that are positioned incorrectly, all other images/text in divs on the page display exactly the same in all other browsers.

The text in IE9 looks to be in the correct position from the left of the window, but is higher than in all other browsers. It happens whether I link my CSS/JavaScript or not.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find that IE handles z-index badly which I think persists in IE9. See [this link here](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) I'm not sure the fix in that post will work for you but it is worth a shot.

Comment: But the wierd thing is, only _those two_ divs are positioned incorrectly, all the others are just fine. What would cause just those divs to be positioned incorrectly?

Comment: Wow, this is wierd man, it fixed itself… it's still off by about a couple pixels, but it's nowhere near as bad as it was before. I dunno what I did that fixed it.